# Best solution to slippy decking?

Tags: resources, gravel

The kids have been slipping on the decking on their run towards the swingset ever since we moved in and I want to sort it out.

The way I see it I have some options

- replace the decking with slabs and possibly gravel
- replace the decking with resin
- replace the decking with anti slip decking
- Retro fit the decking with anti slip stuff
- anti slip varnish??

It's about 2.4m by 7.1m.

I've been looking at this stuff https://www.edecks.co.uk/m/products/8625/219/107/0/Silver-RetroGrip-Anti-Slip-Inserts-(1000mm)/

It looks great but if I was to do all the grooves it would be ridiculously expensive and I'm not sure how many to do to strike the right balance between safe, nice looking and reasonably priced.

Has anyone had a similar dilemma, how did you solve it?

Comment: I wish we could get a product like that where I live.  Have you tried out the free samples listed on their site to see if they fit in the grooves of your deck?

Comment: What are the chances you can't just convince your kids to slow down and be careful?

Comment: Those inserts look like they could be a problem if anyone walks on the deck in bare feet - especially if a barefooted child runs across it and hits a toe. Ouch!

Comment: Is the deck sited at ground level, or raised up - if its raised, by how much? If its at ground level, what's underneath? And are you in the UK?

Comment: Ground level, I ordered a sample of the inserts for about £5, they have two different styles so I ordered one of each :)

Comment: As for the kids, honestly I went out before and found it stupid slippy just walking on it, it's not wonder theyve taken so many tumbles, we had a party mid last year and I'm suprised we didn't send anyone to the hospital lol

Comment: Oh and it's ground level

Comment: @kevinsky there are a couple of products in amazon, like grip tape and grip covers that fit over standard decking but nothing as slick as inserts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My father-in-law used a non-slip deck paint very much like the one shown below to coat his home's deck, porch, and stairs.

[image: Non-skid Deck Paint]

Some specs:

- Type: One-part polyurethane nonskid enamel
- Finish: Low sheen
- Solids by Volume: 54%
- Coverage: 94sq.ft/qt
- Aggregate: Fine mineral bits

It works as advertised and has lasted more than a few years now (in full sun, too). Its only drawback is that the aggregate can make snow shoveling a bit of a pain sometimes. I would hope that something similar would be available in your area.

Comment: That comes up blocked for me (something to do with gdpr) , but it sounds perfect, could you give me the name?

Comment: Converted link to photo and specs.

Answer (score 1):

You've said the deck is at ground level, so it is possible to replace it with paving slabs. However, laying slabs involves a lot of work and cost; there's the digging out, the aggregate then concrete mix to go beneath the slabs, and then the slabs as well. If you wanted pavers, they should be laid on sand, but probably you'd still need to do some digging out as well as  hiring a wacker plate. If you do decide to pave and the area is in shade for a lot of the year, pick a riven or non slip design, because smooth paving slabs can also get very slippery in shady situations.

Presumably your decking already has a framework beneath - if that is still intact, the cheapest and easiest solution is to replace the deck boards with non slip ones, but it's definitely worth costing replacement deck boards against the price of the quantity you'd need of the inserts you've found. The site you linked to in your question also sells non slip decking boards...

If you do decide to replace the deck boards, before buying the replacements, first check the frame beneath to make sure it's in good enough condition to be worth it; also check for signs of mice/rat infestation, because they absolutely love ground level decking to tunnel and nest beneath.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider no slip shoes as opposed to deck treatment. There are industrial/sporting situations where people need to navigate slippery environments, such as sailing yacht decks and restaurant kitchens, so there is an industry specifically designed to provide no slip footwear. A call to the local sailing club or major hotel chain might get some useful comments about how useful this might be.

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of kinds of anti-slip mats that you could lay over the deck, some with drainage holes:

[image: Photo of anti-slip mat]

I found this one at: https://www.rubbercal.com/rubber-mat/anti-slip-floor-mats/